# BeginForm in Partial resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a routing issue I can't figure out:

Partial Method:

```
public ActionResult UserProjMetric(int id, DateTimeOffset? startDate, DateTimeOffset? endDate){
   // some logic code here
   return PartialView("_UserProjMetric", model);
}
```

Main View:

```
<div id="dailyMetric">
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("UserProjMetric", "Users", new { id = Model.Id });
            }
        </div>
```

All of the above works great. The problem I have is inside of the partial I am doing an HTML.BeginForm that isn't working. It claims resource cannot be found.

```
<div class="dateContainer">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("UserProjMetric", "Users", new { id = 23 }))
                        {
                            <span class=""><input type="text" class="startDate dates" placeholder="Start Date" id="from" name="from"></span>
                            <span class=""><input type="text" class="endDate dates" placeholder="End Date" id="to" name="to"></span>
                            <input class="btn btn-small" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        }


                    </div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is `_UserProjMetric` different from `UserProjMetric` ?

Comment: the _UserProjMetric is just the partial view not the controller. One thing to note is that my route looks like so normally....localhost:1234/Users/23. I need it to route to localhost:1234/Users/23/UserProjMetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off defining a model class like:

```
public class UserProjMetricModel
{
   public int id {get; set;} 
   public DateTimeOffset? startDate {get; set;} 
   public DateTimeOffset? endDate {get; set;}
}
```

and then add your action method signature like

```
public ActionResult UserProjMetric(UserProjMetricModel userProjMetric)
```

The router should correctly identify the correct endpoint to route to.

Also, dont forget to remove the id route value `new { id = 23 }` in your view and instead insert it as a hidden field

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserProjMetric", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="23"/>
   <span class=""><input type="text" class="startDate dates" placeholder="Start Date" id="from" name="from"></span>
   <span class=""><input type="text" class="endDate dates" placeholder="End Date" id="to" name="to"></span>
   <input class="btn btn-small" type="submit" value="Submit" />
 }
```

Comment: Did all of this except I had to remove the HttpPost attribute. Because for Html.RenderAction("UserProjMetric", "Users", new UserProjMetricModel { id = Model.Id ?? default(int) }); it apparently doesnt work unless [httppost] is taken out

Comment: @allencoded, did you put  FormMethod.Post in your view for Html.BeginForm? Anyhow, I will remove HttpPost attribute from controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove id=23 from form element and put it as an hidden element inside the form. I think all other code is working.

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="23" />
```

Comment: I did that still claims to not find the reference